# phpinfo() returns blank page in Firefox and asks whether to open or save in IE

Tags: php

I'm trying to update a site that's using php. I built the site and tested it on this machine. But today, the Php won't run on my local machine.

To test, I went back to the most basic php page I have:

```
<?php
phpinfo();

?>
```

When I navigate to this file, in Firefox (28), the result is a blank page. (The page source shows just my code.) In IE 11, I'm asking whether I want to open or save the file.

Searching for my original problem (which was that my php code was showing up rather than running), it was suggested that php wasn't installed. I don't know how it would have gotten uninstalled, but I went ahead and installed it again (from http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx) and still no joy.

Windows 7 SP1

Updates in response to suggestions:

Pardon the beginning stuff, but I'm not primarily a web developer. (I do databases.) This is stuff I'm doing for an organization I'm involved in. I don't actually remember having installed/configured a web server in the first place, nor do I remember having installed php before yesterday (though maybe my son did that for me).

After seeing the replies here, I followed the instructions on this page: http://webmasterjuice.com/how-to-activate-built-in-web-server-windows, but I'm still seeing the same thing.

Update:

I've confirmed that IIS is running and the php was installed. I've followed instructions I found online for getting php working in Windows 7 with IIS. However, it still doesn't make sense to me to have to do this. I'm sure I didn't do any of this when I started working with php. I'm not trying to use my computer as a web server. No interest in working through localhost.

I'm creating the file in a simple web-oriented editor (Crimson Editor). Until recently, I could use the editor's preview function on a file, whether HTML or PHP, and it would run correctly. I'm baffled as to why this stopped working.

Comment: It's not necessarily that PHP wasn't installed, but that your webserver isn't configured to run it; or that you hadn't restarted the webserver after configuring it

Answer (score 1):

A few things to look for:

- It's php running besides been installed? (obvious, but maybe it got killed by some reason)
- Have you included the phpinfo() call inside a html document?

Comment: How do I check whether php is running? I don't see it in either Processes or Services in Task Manager.

Comment: Sorry, but Windows Services fall out of my experience, may others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you named the file with a .php extension and saved it within the document root of the server..?

Comment: Yes, .php extension. I have all the files for this site in a single folder, and until now, had no trouble testing from that folder, that is, using the file:// convention rather than http://